# Saving data as SequenceExample and reading TFRecords for LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, tfrecord

Let's say I have a 3dimentional dataset with shape (sample, timesteps, features) and I want to save it with suitable tensroflow dataset format, e.g. using SequenceExample for further reading with TFRecord and using in LSTM.
There is a dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

data = np.array(
[
    [
        [1 , 10, ],
        [2 , 11, ],
    ],
    [
        [2 , 11, ],
        [3 , 12, ],
    ]
], dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array([101., 202.], dtype=np.float32)
```

There is a model:

```
inputs= tf.keras.layers.Input(
shape=(2, 2),
name='input',
)
model = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
    units=data.shape[2],
    return_sequences=False,
    return_state=False,
    name='lstm',
)(inputs)
model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units=1,
    name='dense',
)(model)
outputs = model
loss = tf.keras.losses.MSE
model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=inputs,
    outputs=outputs,
    name='model',
)
model.compile(
    optimizer='rmsprop',
    loss='mse',
    metrics='mse',
)
model.summary()
model.fit(
    x=data,
    y=y,
    batch_size=1,
)
```

Let's try to save and read dataset using tensorflow API:

```
# writer
options = tf.io.TFRecordOptions(
    compression_type='ZLIB',
    flush_mode=None,
    input_buffer_size=None,
    output_buffer_size=None,
    window_bits=None,
    compression_level=0,
    compression_method=None,
    mem_level=None,
    compression_strategy=None,
)
writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(
    path=r'test.tfrecord',
    options=options,
)
# iterate over each row
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    # set example id
    sample_dict = {
        'index': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[i]))
    }
    features_list = {}
    # iterate over each feature
    for c in range(data[0].shape[1]):
        feature_values = [
            _float_feature(v) for v in data[i][:, c]
        ]
        features_list[str(c)] = tf.train.FeatureList(feature=feature_values)
    # set example
    example = tf.train.SequenceExample(
        context=tf.train.Features(feature=sample_dict),
        feature_lists=tf.train.FeatureLists(feature_list=features_list)
    )
    # write
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()

# read raw
data_raw = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(
    filenames=[r'test.tfrecord'],
    compression_type='ZLIB',
    buffer_size=10*1024, # 10MB
    num_parallel_reads=numexpr.detect_number_of_cores()-1,
)
# parse real
schema = dict(
    zip(
        [str(s) for s in range(data[0].shape[1])],
        [tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.float32)] * data[0].shape[1]
    )
)
def decode_fn(record_bytes):
    context, features = tf.io.parse_single_sequence_example(
        serialized=record_bytes,
        context_features={'index': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)},
        sequence_features=schema,
    )
    return features
# read real
for r in data_raw.map(decode_fn):
    print(r, '\n')
```

When I'm trying to fit model with tensorflow dataset it's getting me an error

```
model.fit(
    data_raw,
    batch_size=1,
)
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=0. Full shape received: []
```

I understand that I did not add label to tensorflow dataset but it does not matter in this case cause dataset has no incomplitable shape. Can anybody help me to understand why and where am I wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I've added decode function and mapped it to tfrecord dataset. This fixed everything. Thx.